# Google API, Python возвращает none

Tags: python, google-maps-api, google-maps

Я столкнулся с проблемой при работе с Google API, использую Python. Проблема в том, что я собираю данные из событий в календаре:

```
    desc = event.get('description')
    evname = event.get('summary')
    loc = event.get('location')
```

Затем, я использую список при определении локации:

```
shoplist = ['Shop1', 'Shop2', 'Shop3', 'Shop4', 'Shop5']
```

Но проблема в том, что если локация пустая, то возвращается значение None, а если оно возвращается, то приложение крашится, так как ничего не находит. Эта строка вызывает проблему:

```
  counter = 0
        for PlaceCount in range(0, 5):
            counter = loc.find(shoplist[PlaceCount])
        print(counter)
```

И как только я не пробовал обозначать пустое значение, например "if loc is none", или еще как, но это не помогает. И, к слову, даже если закоментировать эту строку:

```
counter = loc.find(shoplist[PlaceCount])
```

то приложение все равно на него ссылается и крашится.
Голову сломал, что делать не знаю, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: не пишите крешиться, пишите какое исключение возникает

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Так работает: """for PlaceCount in range(0, 5): if loc: counter = loc.find(shoplist[PlaceCount])"""? Если  нет то киньте ошибку и полный код скрипта.

Comment: Оно работает в том случае, если loc имеет значение, которое находится в shoplist, если оно не находит ничего из значений из shoplist, то выдает ошибку.

Comment: киньте полный код, а то что-то я теряю суть происходящего в скрипте

Comment: https://repl.it/Hqd5/0 
Вот код

Comment: Попробуйте заменить "loc = event.get('location')" на "loc = event.get('location', '')"

Comment: Нет, все равно такая же ошибка

Comment: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'"? Вы уверены что запускете отредактированую версию скрипта?

Comment: Да, совершенно уверен.